# QUTIP output displayed as image in iPython console within Spyder

Tags: ipython, spyder, qutip

I have been having this issue for a while:
Using iPython console in Spyder 2.3.8, and installed QUTIP 3.1.0,
I tried to run a simple code:
    qt.coherent(3,1)
where I was expecting the output to be displayed as an array.
However, doing so in iPython in Spyder it shows an image:

[image: Code]

It seems for some reasons it rendered the array as image, and this is awkward to read in most cases, which I prefer to have the array displayed, which actually works if I use the Python3 console in Spyder.

May I know if you have any idea what the cause maybe?

The weird thing is that, this happens only to my Fedora Scientific 23, to the Spyder3 running Python3.4.

Another computer running Windows and WinPython didn't share the same problem, which the array got displayed correctly.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) Could you post a full example of the code you're trying to run so we can test what's happening in our side? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the ipython in spyder is calling the latex_repr method rather than just repr. Seems to be a bug somewhere in spyder as the standard ipython terminal has no such error.

Comment: It's been a while when I have this problem, I can't say for sure I remember the details. But as I typed above, I vaguely remember the Spyder which I got from WinPython on Windows didn't have the same display issue. Could be a different version of Spyder. Now I switched to Jupyter which works perfectly well in terms of this, so I no longer intend to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The image printing problem appears when I automatically loaded SymPy which is done by: *go to spyder Tools>>Prefeneces>>Ipython console>> Advance setting>> check or uncheck symbolic mathematic*

When I check the symbolic mathematic, I generally get the result as an image, so I uncheck it and restart spyder, now it works well.

However, if you want to calculate something from symbolic math, it is better to check the "symbolic math" box again. I try to load sympy to ipython but I  constantly get a typeerror.